How to use an encrypted application.properties with Spring Boot?
I have read a few articles on how to encrypt passwords in application.properties file but I want to encrypt the entire application.properties file. I know how to do this using command-line tools. My question is that given an encrypted application.properties file together with public key, how can I tell Spring Boot to decrypt and parse out the config in a ConfigurationProperties class?

Implement your own PropertySourceLocator or EnvironmentPostProcessor and register them with spring.factories
